# Understanding function returns

Tags: javascript, function

I'm creating a simple function and want to save the value to a var. Why do i have to write a return?

Knowing the Solution, but havin understanding problems.

```js
function a() {
  console.log('This is a Test.');
}
let b = a();
console.log(b);
```

Result would be:

```
This is a Test.
Undefined
```

Questions:

1. Where is the first function call (This is a Test)?  I thought let b
   = a(); would only define the var b, and not actually run the a() function? So every Variable-Declaration var c = myfunc() results
   actually in running the myfunc() function?
2. Why would then b = undefined, if the actual function-call (a())
   prints This is a Test.

The Solution would obviously be that function a() returns nothing. In my understanding, function a() actually "returns" This is a Test cause console.log() would run?

Comment: Printing is not returning.

Comment: `let b = a();` sets `b` to the result of the `a` function. If you want b to be a copy of the function then the syntax would be `let b = a;` and you would call it `b();` after it's assigned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Every function in JavaScript returns a value

Good question: the key is that *every* function in JavaScript returns a value, whether you give it a return value or not.  If you don't tell JavaScript what to return using the `return` keyword, then it returns the builtin JavaScript value of `undefined`.

## You didn't tell it what to return, so it returned *undefined*

So in your case, you're telling the JavaScript interpreter to execute the function `a` and then set the variable `b` to the value returned by `a`. Since you never specified what `a` should return, it returns the builtin value of `undefined`, which is why you're seeing what you're seeing in the console logs.

## A word about console.logs vs. returning values

Something that may help: your function `a` calls `console.log` to print `'This is a Test.'` to the console. This is not the same as telling `a` to return the string `'This is a Test.'`. It is an *action* that your function performs whenever it is called. Without a return value, your function still returns `undefined`.

## What you probably wanted to do

It sounds like you probably wanted your function `a` to return the string `'This is a Test.'` rather than print it to the console itself.  This can be done with the following change to your function:

```
function a() {
   return 'This is a test.';
}
```

Comment: don't use heavy bold text like this for ordinary answers

Comment: @user633183 Lots of answers are formatted like this--I think it's a preference thing.  Some people love it, some hate it, most may not care much.  But it helps skimmers find the important info quickly by making the answer easy to parse.

Comment: The previous commenter's point notwithstanding, I *would* encourage you to change the bolded and italicized JS keywords (e.g., `return` and `undefined`) to inline code blocks for the sake of clarity and readability.

Comment: Sure thing, will do.

Comment: Okay added code tags--lemme know if I overdid it, or feel free to edit it directly, either is fine.

Comment: Ty Sir for this easy understandable Answer. I already did know the Solution, the main Question was the "Why". Greetz!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!